# How to detect glare in image using open-cv python?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to detect that the below shown images are bad images. Can anyone suggest a method or algorithm to detect glare and which can classify a bad image and good image? I have tried Template matching/ Feature matching, but it didn't work for my case. Also if possible the algorithm should work environment independent.

[image]
[image]

I had tried this algorithm(Template Matching):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 35

img1 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/LB-185/Downloads/imgs/after_thresh/19_12_53_964057.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/LB-185/Downloads/imgs/after_thresh/19_12_54_355454.png',0)          # trainImage

sift = cv2.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)       #finding keypoints and descriptors from img 1
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)       #finding keypoints and descriptors from img 2

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)
if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print ("Not enough matches are found - {}{}".format(len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
    matchesMask = None
    
draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), singlePointColor = None, matchesMask = matchesMask, flags = 2)# # draw only inliers draw matches in green color

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

//////////////////////////

I had to classify the below given image into good image and the above mentioned image as bad image.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66948586/edit) the post to include your own effort into solving this problem. The latter preferably in code, this is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

A simple thresholding method might work well for you.

1. Convert the image to grayscale.
2. Threshold values that are larger than 250 for example.
3. Count the number of nonzeros.
4. If the count is larger than say 1% of the image size then the image should be classified as glared.

Comment: Actually, I tried the similar algorithm, but the conflict that I face is it will be environment dependent. I need to develop an algorithm which is environment independent (does not depend on shape of light source or intensity of light source)

Comment: I see. You can try training a simple CNN as a classifier.
Have a look at this: [Fast glare detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.05189)

Comment: Okay, tysm i will try this out.